# Create Function Date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to create a function with 2 params. 
1st param is the date
2nd is an int

```
What i want the function to do:

Function('2014-04-20', 5) results in '2013-11-20'
Function('2013-11-10', 2) results in '2013-09-10'

CREATE FUNCTION MonthDiff(
            @in_date DATE
           ,@in_mn_adjust INT)
            RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
            DECLARE @in_new DATE;

            SET @in_new = DATEADD(MM, -@in_mn_adjust, @in_date);


            RETURN @in_new;
END;
```

I ran 'select dbo.monthdifference('2014-04-22', 3). The error that I got is Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is only 1 line in your function and you don't manipulate arguments in any way, so I would say your function is useless... but maybe am I missing something ? Why not simply using the built-in function as this extra abstraction does nothing ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to left out that this is a dumb down version of the function im attempting to create. There will be more criteria and requirements but that part should be easy once I implement the 'Ifs' and such. Just need to figure out the erro

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to solve your problem.

```
Declare @str Varchar(10)

Declare @result Varchar(10)

set @str= '2012/10/23'

set @result = DATEADD(MONTH,-2,CONVERT(date,@str,102))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes SQL Server does silly things and misinterprets some date strings<sup>1</sup>. The following formats are *always* safe. I believe there are some other formats that are also safe when dealing with the newer `date`, `time` and `datetime2` types but I tend to play it safe:

```
YYYYMMDD
YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss
YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.mil
```

So try:

```
select dbo.monthdifference('20140422', 3)
```

---

(The 'T' in my example formats is the literal character `T`, being used as a separator, instead of a space, and instead of the other characters in those format strings which are placeholders, so e.g. `2014-04-24T09:23:00` is in one of my listed safe formats)

---

<sup>1</sup>For example, if your language settings are British it interprets `nnnn-nn-nn`, where all `n`s are digits, as a `YYYY-DD-MM` format - despite the fact that I doubt that anyone in Britain would attempt such an interpretation.